# Gradle not handling Maven parent POMs with version-range

Tags: gradle, dependencies, parent, maven

I have a Gradle build that needs to fetch dependencies from a Nexus repo that has been populated using Maven. Some of the POMs there use version-ranges when specifying a parent POM.

In my build.gradle I put a dependency:

```
compile group: 'com.company.platform', name: 'abc-common', version: '[11.0,12.0['
```

The Gradle logs show that a request is made for the versions of abc-common, and its POM and its parent's POM are fetched:

```
abc-common-11.0.7-17042111.pom:
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.company.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>abc-parent</artifactId>
        <version>11.0.7-17042111</version>
        <relativePath>..</relativePath>
    </parent>

abc-parent-11.0.7-17042111.pom:
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.company.corporate</groupId>
        <artifactId>corporate-parent</artifactId>
        <version>[11.0.7,11.0.8)</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
```

But Gradle fails to fetch the corporate-parent POM. Instead of requesting what versions are present on the repo, it tries to fetch using the version-range literal:

```
Loading http://nexus.company.com:8081/.../corporate-parent/[11.0.7,11.0.8)/corporate-parent-[11.0.7,11.0.8).pom
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a known problem with Gradle? Is there a work-around?

Any help is much appreciated. This is a show-stopper for me. If I can't find a solution, it's back to Maven.